# Create Attributes and Linking Attributes to Product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having trouble creating attributes for products using WooCommerce. For example I have products that have different color. So the main attribute is *Color* and the Variables would be *Red*, *Orange* and *Purple*.

I have tried the following but I am unable to set it.

```php
wp_set_object_terms( 165, 'Color', 'pa_colour' );
wp_set_object_terms( 165, Array("Red", "Orange", "Purple"), 'pa_colour' );
```

How do I create the attributes first and link them to the product? Is there any simple way to first create the attribute then create the variables to link to product?

Update:
I've been able to do some research and able to create the attribute.

```php
$wpdb->insert(
    $wpdb->prefix . 'woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies',
    array(
        'attribute_label'   => $data['attributelabel'],
        'attribute_name'    => $data['attributename'],
        'attribute_type'    => $data['attributetype'],
        'attribute_orderby' => $data['attributeorder'],
    )
);
```

However, when I tried the following code:

```php
wp_set_object_terms (165, 'variable', 'product_type');
wp_set_object_terms( 165, Array("ta", "tb"), 'pa_testing' );
```

I check the backend I see the product is linked to the attribute however the textbox for the values are missing. I am not able to even enter the variation page for the product.

Anyone have any idea?